# Dell Inspiron 3537 not accepting BIOS system password

Tags: bios, dell-inspiron, password-recovery

Everything was working the previous night, in the morning I powered on my Dell Inspiron 3537 (2014), I entered the credentials as usual but System password says incorrect.
I had password in HDD and System BIOS. HDD password was working but System isn't.
I've tried CMOS option, generating master password using bios-pw[dot]org but all I see is 16 character code unlike latest models which this website has the option of.
I remember my password very well, I've been using the same since 2 years.
Dell customer service asks to contact local service center which is 100 miles away.

**UPDATE:**
I contacted Dell, they said, I must have forgotten password while I very well know my password. Also, I did not change my password since 1 and a half years or so. Plus they need my complete laptop and no guarantee for transition breakage which I presume they will do it eventually to get more money out of my pockets.

Comment: please do what they say. Nobody here can give a magical solution.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia please read update. I did what you said. Also, I do not need a magical solution. I read somewhere that "due to power issues BIOS is unable to recognize my password" can be the issue. I am indeed hoping for technical diagnostics and solution thereof.